# Can't create subscription button in sandbox (redirects to live site)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Tell me if I'm doing something wrong here.

1. I go to developer.paypal.com
2. login with my real PayPal account
3. go to Applications->Sandbox accounts
4. click Enter Sandbox site
5. login with the business test account I created
6. click Merchant Services
7. click on "Create payment buttons for your website."

From step 5 up until this point, the URL in the address bar has been sandbox.paypal.com, but the "Create payment buttons for your website" button takes me to:

```
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=acct_setup/Setup_Solution_WPS&fli=true
```

That's the live site, correct?

If I create a button at the above URL that I'm directed to, then login to the sandbox site again and go to "My Saved Buttons," there aren't any buttons there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is obviously just a bug on the PayPal website. The "Create payment buttons for your website" button goes to the live PayPal website instead of the sandbox, but I found a workaround.

1. Click on Merchant Services
2. Click on "My saved buttons"
3. Click on "Create new button"

That kept me in the sandbox site and allowed me to create a button.